# cannot locate .htaccess file in tomcat/apache configuration

Tags: apache, tomcat, url-rewriting

I have installed tomcat and apache on my ubuntu machine for development of a jsp-based website. I need to configure a url_rewrite and therefore need access to the .htaccess file. Can you please help me locate it?

Thanks,

Leonard

Comment: Please tell us what you want to do. Normally Apache (httpd) and Tomcat are not connected. Do you want httpd to proxy http requests and forward they to the tomcat? Are you using mod_proxy_... or mod_jk? Please tell us how you have already configured httpd and tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to exist already. You can make it yourself in the document root. Make sure AllowOverride All is set in your conf file :)